# Cannot covert to JSON value the result of Element.getBoundingClientRect()

Tags: javascript

I need to convert to a JSON value the result of a DOMRect object returned by `Element.getBoundingClientRect()`

Here an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/5vs6x6fc/2/

When using `JSON.stringify()` it returns `{}`, I need the JSON value instead.

I would like to know:

- Why is that?
- What could be a possible solution alternative to looping to the property of the returned object `r` ex: `for (var property in r){}`

Notes: I am targeting Chrome.

Comment: Loot at this issue https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1100611

Comment: event properties are the same way and there is no easy one-liner afaik.

Comment: So the take away seems to be that it "doesn't work" because the object doesn't own the properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bounding rect only contains "virtual" properties. If you

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(r));
// or
console.log(Object.keys(r));
```

you'll get an empty list. `JSON.stringify()` depends on `Object.keys(r)` (see comments below) and thus returns an empty object literal.

Your loop-based approach seems to be a feasible solution to this problem.

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` technically uses same names as the mere `Object.keys()` list...

Comment: Oh ok, didn't know that. But result is the same.